# UITableView text color blur issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have two UITableViews. One of the tables is working fine but the UILabels in the other table is blurry. I have tried changing their color programmatically. It can change the color ex: black to green but the blurry issue still remains.

[image: blurry text]

This is my hierarchy of this particular view
[image: hierarchy]

How can I make the text clear like the first table?

Comment: pls show your code

Comment: for cell of rowpathindex? i'm creating the table programmatically tho.. @NilayShah

Comment: do you check the font color which you are setting in storyboard and in code ?

Comment: first I tried in storyboard but failed,then I tried in code.. it looks very transparent @R.Mohan

Comment: add the code where you are setting the textcolor for those labels, and what is the alpha value you are setting there ?

Comment: select that label from story board and select color click on color and check opacity in that set it to 100

Answer (score 0):

Set shouldRasterize = false on the CGLayer of the view containing the UILabel.

And

Your label is blurry because the frame is using floating numbers.

To force integers value for your frame just do :

```
[loadingText setFrame:CGRectIntegral(loadingText.frame)];
```

Comment: are you try this view.layer.shouldRasterize = false

Comment: add a second sol please check.

Comment: i tried your suggestion will cell, parent view,table and text also but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

You might have changed the alpha value of any of the superviews of `UITableView`. If you changed a view's alpha value, it affects all the subview's alpha